# GSON sends my object as a string not a object

Tags: android, json, parsing, object, gson

I am using Volley with GSON and I need to send a object as a parameter to my call.

This is how I do the object:

```
JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(route);
params.put("route", json);
```

And then I call my Volley JsonObjectRequest function.

The problem is that the params look like this:

```
{"route":"{\"bounds\":{\"northeast\":{\"lat\":52.3777194,\"lng\":4.924666999999999},\"southwest\":{\"lat\":52.36881109999999,\"lng\":4.9011479}},\"copyrights\":\"Map data ©2014 Google\", etc...}"
```

As you can see, instead of sending it as a object, its sending it as a String , and that's why I get the " before the {} (before the object begins). The params should look like:

```
   {"route":{\"bounds\":{\"northeast\":{\"lat\":52.3777194,\"lng\":4.924666999999999},\"southwest\":{\"lat\":52.36881109999999,\"lng\":4.9011479}},\"copyrights\":\"Map data ©2014 Google\", etc...}
```

So no " before { like this:

```
{"route":{myObject}
```

What an I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you double json-encoding that inner structure? json encoding should be done ONCE, when the entire data structure is complete. Once you've json-encoded something, it's a string. and encoding it again will simply encode that string into yet another json string, with all json-metachars escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to mix `JSONObject` and `GSON`.
That's 2 different libraries.

Use `gson.toJsonTree` to obtain an element, then use `JsonObject` instead of `JSONObject`:

```
JsonObject params = new JsonObject();
Gson gson = new Gson();
params.add("route", gson.toJsonTree(route));
```

Comment: the problem is that JsonObjectRequest from Volley asks in the constructor for the "org.json.JSONOBJECT" instead of the com.google.Json.JsonObject, how can I resolve this?

Comment: creating a custom JsonRequest object to do that should not take more that 20 lines. look at the implementation of `JsonObjectRequest` for inspiration